# I want to create a user on Google Duo through Java Rest api. Followed documentation but getting error

Tags: java, java-8, rest

I am creating a Java Rest api to create users on Google Duo admin. I am following the documentation https://duo.com/docs/adminapi and I have added auth and date/time header but still I am getting unauthorised error 401. Can anyone guide me what am I doing wrong I have read the doc and added all the mandatory headers.

```
public static void POSTRequest() throws IOException {
    String userCredentials = "Username:Password";
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
    String dateTime = OffsetDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
    String POST_PARAMS = "{\n" + "\"userId\": 101,\r\n" +
            "    \"id\": 101,\r\n" +
            "    \"title\": \"Test Title\",\r\n" +
            "    \"body\": \"Test Body\"" + "\n}";
    URL obj = new URL("https://api-e9770554.duosecurity.com");

    HttpURLConnection postConnection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    postConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    postConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    postConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
    postConnection.setRequestProperty("Date", dateTime);
    postConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = postConnection.getOutputStream();
    os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();

    int responseCode = postConnection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :  " + responseCode);
    System.out.println("POST Response Message : " + postConnection.getResponseMessage());

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) { //success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        postConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("POST NOT WORKED");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
{
  "code": 40101,
  "message": "Missing request credentials",
  "stat": "FAIL"
}

Response code: 401 (Unauthorized); Time: 2022ms; Content    length: 73 bytes
```

Comment: Try `basicAuth = "Bearer " + ...` instead

Comment: Isn’t there a Duo SDK? Why are you using the REST services with Java when an SDK is provided?

Comment: 401 means "unauthorized", i.e. API is closed from external use.

Answer (score 0):

You may use like below:

1. Add below dependency to pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.duosecurity</groupId>
       <artifactId>duo-client</artifactId>
       <version>0.6.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. User below code:

   ```
    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
   import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
   import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
   import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
   import javax.crypto.Mac;
   import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
   import java.net.URLEncoder;
   import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
   import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
   import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
   import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Base64;
   import java.util.SortedMap;
   import java.util.TreeMap;

   public class AdminAPIExample {

       private static SortedMap<String, Object> params = new TreeMap<String, Object>();

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           String ikey = "x";
           String skey = "x";
           String host = "x";
           String httpMethod = "POST";
           String requestPath = "/auth/v2/auth";

           String timestamp = OffsetDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);

           params.put("username","20230612");
           params.put("factor","push");
           params.put("device","auto");

           String queryString = canonQueryString();
          System.out.println("queryString = " + queryString);



           String canonicalRequest = timestamp +"\n" + httpMethod.toUpperCase() +"\n" + host.toLowerCase() +"\n"+requestPath +"\n" +queryString;
           System.out.println("canonicalRequest = " + canonicalRequest);

           String signature = sign2(canonicalRequest, skey);
           System.out.println("signature = " + signature);

           String url = "https://" + host.toLowerCase() + requestPath+"?"+queryString;
           System.out.println("url = " + url);

           String authString ="Basic "+ Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((ikey + ":" + signature).getBytes());
           System.out.println("authString = " + authString);
           System.out.println("authString length= " + authString.length());


           HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
           HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
           httpPost.setHeader("Date", timestamp);
           httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", authString);
           httpPost.setHeader("Host", host.toLowerCase());
           httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


           // Make the request
           HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
           String responseContent = entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : "";

           String rs =  "Response Status Code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + "\nResponse Content:\n" + responseContent;
           System.out.println("rs = " + rs);
       }

       public static String canonQueryString()
               throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
           ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();

           for (String key : params.keySet()) {
               String name = URLEncoder
                       .encode(key, "UTF-8")
                       .replace("+", "%20")
                       .replace("*", "%2A")
                       .replace("%7E", "~");
               String value = URLEncoder
                       .encode(params.get(key).toString(), "UTF-8")
                       .replace("+", "%20")
                       .replace("*", "%2A")
                       .replace("%7E", "~");
               args.add(name + "=" + value);
           }

           return com.duosecurity.client.Util.join(args.toArray(), "&");
       }

       private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
           StringBuilder hexStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           for (byte b : bytes) {
               hexStringBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
           }
           return hexStringBuilder.toString();
       }

       static String sign2(String data, String secretKey){
           try {

               byte[] secretKeyBytes = secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
               byte[] messageBytes = data.getBytes("UTF-8");

               // Create a secret key specification
               SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyBytes, "HmacSHA1"); // Use a suitable HMAC algorithm

               // Initialize the HMAC with the secret key
               Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1"); // Use the same HMAC algorithm
               mac.init(secretKeySpec);

               // Calculate the HMAC
               byte[] hmacBytes = mac.doFinal(messageBytes);

               // Convert the HMAC to a hexadecimal string
               StringBuilder hexStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
               for (byte b : hmacBytes) {
                   hexStringBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
               }
               String hexHMAC = hexStringBuilder.toString();

               // Print the hex HMAC
               System.out.println(hexHMAC);



               return hexHMAC;
           } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return null;
       }

   }
   ```

Note: All Other API are similar. **Just change your intregation key, Secrete key, host, end point and parameters.**